# Tomcat taking too long to initialize

Tags: tomcat7

Why would it take 40+ minutes for the server to initialize the 'http-bio-8443' protocol handler as highlighted below.
This line is  single handedly causing all the tomcat startup delay.

```
Mar 30, 2015 10:12:49 AM.    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
************************************
Mar 30, 2015 10:12:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Mar 30, 2015 10:55:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
************************************
Mar 30, 2015 10:55:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
```

Answer (score 0):

The OS does not have enough entropy to initialise the cryptography used by the HTTPS connector.

Comment: The OS in question is windows. Can you please elaborate on what you are suggesting? re-install the OS maybe?